# Fisica.init() isn't recognized by its own library

Tags: java, processing, physics

To use the fisica library for processing you first need to use the command

```
import fisica.*;
void setup() 
{
//...
Fisica.init(this);
//...
}
```

Doing that, though, results in the error: 'The function `init(Fisica)` doesn't exist'.
Removing the command gives the error: 
'Fisica$LibraryNotInitializedException: Must call `Fisica.init(this);` before using this library.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Is your `setup()` method declared in a class called `Fiscia` by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wager that you've declared this method in a class called `Fisica`:

```
import fisica.*;

class Fisica {
  void setup() 
  {
    //...
    Fisica.init(this);
    //...
  }
}
```

So `Fisica` in `Fisica.init` refers to your class, which doesn't have a static init method.

Either fully-qualify the invocation of `Fisica`:

```
fisica.Fisica.init(this);
```

or call your class something different (this is almost certainly the better choice, since it avoids confusion in other places too).

Comment: Thanks, I'd never have guessed it

Answer (score 0):

The error resulted from calling the class I was working on "Fisica" as well. Changing the name of the file solved the problem.